# Windows: Can't create files on admin$ share even as administrator

Tags: windows, networking, network-share

Using Win10 x64 Pro.

In the past I was to be able to copy and files to \mylocalmachine\admin$ when using an account that is an administrator of the system.  However, now I can only list and read files, but not write or delete files.

I can still do it from c:\windows directly if on the local system with the same account, but even on that system `del \\machinename\admin$\myfile` gives access is access denied as does trying to copy a file to it.

What might be going on here?  How do I get it to work like it always had (I haven't done this in a log time, so some Windows update may have broke it with a new "feature").

TIA!!

Comment: Read up on LocalAccountFilterTokenpolicy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction

Comment: But I'm a domain user and a member of the local Administrators group on the computer (I don't think I'm on the Domain Admin group though).

Comment: if you want to use files why not natively using C$ as admin?

Comment: Because Admin$ goes to %systemroot% whereas C$ is to the C drive and windows may not be in C:\Windows.